# How do I approximate the inner product of trigonometric functions with a small perturbation?

Tags: perturbation-theory

I learned that $\int_0^1 \cos(n \pi t)\cos(m \pi t)~\mathrm{d}t = 1/2$ for any positive $m$ and $n$, becuase of the orthogonality of trigonometric functions. If one of the basis function $\cos(m\pi t)$ has a small perturbation (i.e. $\cos(m \pi (t+\epsilon f(t)))$), I was wondering if I could approximate such a integral by using something like:
$$
\int_0^1 \cos(n \pi t)\cos(m \pi (t+\epsilon f(t)))~\mathrm{d}t\approx\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon g_1(m,n)+\cdots
$$
where $n\geq 1$ and $m\geq 1$ are positive integers, and $|f(t)|<1$ for any $0\leq t\leq 1$ with $\epsilon\ll 1$. If so, how could we obtain the expression of unknown function $g_1(m,n)$?

Comment: In that form where the perturbation is a time change, you would probably want to just Taylor expand the cosine, so $\cos(m\pi(t+\epsilon f(t))) \sim \cos(m\pi t) - \epsilon f(t) m \pi \sin(m \pi t)$. The problem is that now you have a question of how to integrate $\cos(n \pi t) \sin(m \pi t) f(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. If I understood correctly, Taylor expansion is only valid if the deviation, i.e. $m\pi f(t)\epsilon$ is small. If $m$ is sufficiently large, the error of Taylor expansion could be quite big, isn't it?

Comment: That is true, but on the other hand cos is analytic and the other cos is bounded, so you can always take enough terms to ensure that the error is small. You just might need to take $k$ very large so that $(m\epsilon)^k/k!$ is small. I am not sure whether there is any Fourier-based method you can use in this situation of a small phase shift in a high frequency wave.